# Why CSS files not loading when compressing HTTP response using GZipStream?

Tags: c#, compression, asp.net-2.0, gzip, httpcontext

I am developing an application using asp.net 2.0 (C#), in which I am trying to implement the compression of my files, so that performance of my website will improve.

For that I have added a code in my Global.asax file to compress all requests (.aspx, .js, .css) But when I am running my application it works well for first time then the CSS is not loading and web page is not rendering properly.

Why its happening??

**Edited (added my compression code)**

My compression code of Global.asax file is as follows:

```
void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        HttpContext incoming = HttpContext.Current;
        string oldpath = incoming.Request.Path.ToLower();

        incoming.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(incoming.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-encoding"] = true;
    }
```

Also please let me know if there is any other better way to do the same, using the Global.asax file, because I don't have access of IIS Settings and also I don't have permission to implement the HttpModule, that is why I am using Global.asax file.

Thanks

Comment: id post your compression code if you want people to diagnose it ;)

Comment: addec compression code! please diagnose it for better performance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For static files, you can configure IIS to do the compression for you, no need to implement it yourself.

In IIS6 this is a global setting (properties of the "Web Sites" node in IIS manager, service tab).

In IIS7 this is set on a per folder basis, and it will also compress dynamic content for you. It can either be set in IIS Manager or in the [web.config](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/urlCompression) file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I can't caz I don't have access to IIS settings as I am on Shared Hosting server.

Comment: In IIS7 you will be able to set this in a web.config file (all IIS7 settings are just web.config entries). For IIS6 that would be a problem. Which version of IIS are you using?

Comment: I am using IIS7, please tell me what settings I have to add in we.config file. Please ??

Comment: Done, the link takes you to the reference for <system.webServer> which is the section used for IIS7 configuration not relating directly to ASP.NET.

Comment: Yups, done. But in the urlCompression tag "doDynamicCompression" is false. When I am setting it truw then My pages are gzipped, else they are not.

Comment: Also on the link you have given a note is written which says: 
"Note: Use of dynamic compression may increase processor utilization and reduce the overall performance of the Web server."

Comment: But as far as I know its recommended that you should compress (http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip) your contents before serving them. Then why that not is given there.

Comment: IIS does cache the static files once compressed (the size and location of this cache is set at the server level).

Comment: The performance trade off cannot be answered in general, except that with CPU growing faster than memory and network bandwidth, compression overheads are being less significant. Only you can make this trade off.